# How do i make a Jar file from an already existing Jar and my own classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

For example I want to create a Jar file C.jar from A.Jar(like from rt.jar from Jre) and my own classes(Ex.java file).
I am using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you want to create Jar file using eclipse
  then you can follow [this link](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm). Put your class files and existing A.jar then perform export operation to create C.jar.
- If you want to create Jar file using cmd then use `jar cf C.jar *.jar *.class` command to create new Jar file with classes as well as existing A.jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven to build your jar then you can make use of the maven-assembly-plugin. This plugin will build a jar that will contain your code as well as all packages contained in the project's dependencies. See here for the documentation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/